# How to move graph on core plot to show the y

Tags: iphone, ios, core-plot

I have a graph, but it I can only see what ahppensis when a new point is added I can only see 1 - 10 and I have to scroll up to see where the most recent data point is. how can I make it so the y is in the middle so like 5 above and below where the y point is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the `yRange` when you add new data.

Comment: like how would I do it?

Comment: `plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(y - 5.0) length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(10.0)];`